# ngFor with Hammer JS swipe function in Angular 7

Tags: angular, hammer.js, hammer

While using Hammer js swipe function with *ngFor in angular.The result expected was a swipe for particular index of tile and that tile will be removed. But by doing that the animation is not working now. the code which i have done is in below link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animations-lib-demo-ahykzr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arjun, you use an unique variable to control the animations, that's for all the div you has

```
 [@cardAnimator]="animationState"
```

So, when change the variable all the div are animated.

You need use an array of variables

declare animationState as an array of strings

```
animationState: string[]=[];
```

En startAnimation and resetAnimation use the array

```
   startAnimation(state,index) {
    console.log(state)
        console.log(index)

    this.asd = index;
    if (!this.animationState[index]) {
      this.animationState[index] = state;
    }
  }
  

  resetAnimationState(index) {
    this.animationState[index] = '';
  }
```

And in .html use also the array

```
[@cardAnimator]="animationState[i]" 
(@cardAnimator.done)="resetAnimationState(i)"
```

See in your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animations-lib-demo-rjyjj3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** I change cardAnimator.done to pass as argument the index, so I can forget the "ugly" `asd` variable

Comment: @arjunmnairarjun, note: I just improve the answer to forget the "ugly" `asd` variable

Comment: ok just one more dout i tried to remove the tile by using index in array by


 startAnimation(state,index) {
    this.asd = index;
   if (!this.animationState[index]) {
      this.animationState[index] = state;
    }
    this.datas.splice(this.asd, 1);
  }
but the animation is not coming then